# Prevent okhttp3 using http2 with Frida

Tags: android, okhttp, http2, frida, http-1.1

I debug an Android application with Frida that using okhttp3 library.

How can I prevent that library using HTTP2 and using only HTTP1.1?

When I run https://codeshare.frida.re/@BenGardiner/android-list-loaded-classes/ I got lot of classes for example :

```
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnectionPool
okhttp3.internal.http.HttpMethod
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor
```

Comment: Have you tried to load the class directly after listing all classes? Because there seems to be a problem in Frida that certain classes are not available unless they are used for the first time. Not sure why and how but I and others here on SO have made this experience. I would recommend to try loading the `RealConnection` class first using Java class loader (system classloader or Class.forName for example) as workaround for this problem.

Comment: @Robert I can load `okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection` ... what is next step?

Comment: Afterwards I would assume it should also be available in Frida for hooking. For disabling HTTP2 I would check the code of okhttp3 at github. I would assume that there is an option to enable/disable HTTP2. See for example this code https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/79f50e1911e50e3360b25c318999d1274f0a7b8a/okhttp/src/jvmTest/java/okhttp3/ConnectionReuseTest.kt#L307-L327